# I can't use the `node app.js` command in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, bots, discord

I am trying to make a Discord bot and you can make your bot become online and active by running the `node app.js` command, but when I run that, I get this error:

`node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ node app.js
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Either you do not have Node.js installed or Visual Studio Code is just not picking it up that you have it in general and you will have to re install node.

Here's a link for [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

Answer (score 0):

## "The term '...' was not recognized as a cmdlet or (...)"

This error means that "the program (x) was not found in your `PATH` variable."

### What is `PATH`?

`PATH` can be seen as the "search path" for programs -- which would you rather type?

```
C:\Program Files\Node.js\bin\node
```

or

```
node
```

<sup>paths are not really the Node for Windows paths</sup>

The way you can type the second one is because your `PATH` specifies `C:\Program Files\Node.js\bin` as one of the locations to search for binaries.

### So, how can I fix this?

You either need to modify your `PATH` environment variable (the Node installer does this for you), or more likely, **install Node.js.**

#### Windows

Download and run the installer from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and then try again.

#### GNU/Linux

Also, if you think you've installed Node for Linux, check your `PATH` with this command:

```sh
echo "$PATH"
```

Usually it looks something like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

If `/usr/local/bin` isn't specified here, check your `/etc/profile` and fix it.

Debian, Ubuntu

Search up how to use "nodesource debian repos", or for an older version:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs npm
node -v # shows node version
npm -v  # and npm version
```

Arch Linux

Just install Node from the official repos: `pacman -S nodejs`

openSUSE

Just install Node with zypp: `zypper install nodejs`

Other Distros

Not sure about others, sorry.